# Roman page numbering is misaligned in TOC, LOF and LOT for page numbers >30

Tags: table-of-contents, roman-numerals

the document I am working on has an extensive amount of reference pages and appendices. I am using a twosided *scrartcl* and overall I did not run into any problems when compiling. However, I just happen to notice that the roman page numbering for the TOC, LOF and LOT are all misaligned for values larger than 30. I am quite confused by this and cannot find anything on this issue. Does someone know how to indent the larger numbers to right-align the items with the rest?

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[%
english,
DIV=10,
paper=a4,
fontsize=11pt,
numbers=noenddot,
pagesize,
draft=false,
twoside,
BCOR=10mm,
openright,
captions=tableheading,
toc=bibliography,
toc=listof
]{scrartcl}

%Math and Table Packages
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm, amstext}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,longtable,array,multirow}
    \usepackage{tabu}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

%Font Packages
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
    \setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{microtype}

%Utility Packages
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage[toc,page,title]{appendix}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \captionsetup{textfont={footnotesize},labelfont={small,bf}, labelsep=period}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[hang]{footmisc} 

    \usepackage[
    colorlinks,%
    linktocpage,%
    linktoc=all,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    citecolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black
    ]{hyperref}


%Manual Document Settings
    \usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \KOMAoptions{headsepline=true,footsepline=false,plainfootsepline=false}

    \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{%
        \normalfont\normalcolor\scshape\footnotesize}
    \setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\normalsize}

    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat*{\paragraph}{\sffamily\small\bfseries}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

    \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
    \setlength\footnotemargin{8pt}

    \usepackage{apacite} 
    \bibliographystyle{apacite}  

    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
```

[image: I cropped the issue into one image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This is a well known bad feature of Roman numbers and not of LaTeX ;-) I think this is also why we don't use Roman numbers in our everyday's calculations or notation of numbers ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! Cannot believe how quick you were. Sad to hear that you dont know a fix for this, however good to hear that it is not due to a screw up on my side.

Comment: I have a quick fix: Don't use Roman numbers for the main document parts, at most for the first few pages, then use `\pagenumbering{arabic}`. I am no KOMA class user, so I have no suggestions for you how to correct this misalignment

Comment: In many LaTeX classes, you can change the amount of space for the page numbers by doing something like `\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{1.55em}` `\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em}` `\@pnumwidth` is the width allowed for the page number. `\@tocrmarg` is the width for the right hand margin of the table of contents - often 1.0em bigger than `\@pnumwidth`. I don't know if this works for `scrartcl` - so read the documentation! Note you need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to redefine these macros containing `@` in the name. 1.55em and 2.55em are the default sizes in the "standard" LaTeX classes.

Comment: By adjusting \renewcommand{\@pnumwidth} to 2.5em the problem was solved. Thank you very much!

Comment: @alephzero -- i think you snould write an answer.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Someone somewhere on this website was suggesting using `\mainmatter` rather than `\pagenumbering{arabic}` but I might be misremembering and I didn't try.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: `\mainmatter`, well, if really needed ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Alephzero in the comments, the spacing can be altered with

```
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{}
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{}
```

The former adjusts the width allowed for the page numbers *(standard value is 1.55em)* while the latter adjusts the width for the margin on the right hand side *(standard value is 2.55em)*. Both did work with the documentclass *scrartcl*. I solved my misalignment with

```
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{2.6em} 
\makeatother
```