# Large Page Numbers Using Roman Page Numbering Don't Align as Expected in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, numbering

**Description of the Problem**

When using Roman page numbering, large page numbers don't align as expected in the table of content (TOC). I would expect them to be right-aligned just like Arabic numbers.

**Preview of the Problem**

[image]

**Quick Fix of the Problem Proposed by [@alephzero](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384991/roman-page-numbering-is-misaligned-in-toc-lof-and-lot-for-page-numbers-30)**

[@alephzero](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384991/roman-page-numbering-is-misaligned-in-toc-lof-and-lot-for-page-numbers-30) proposed to add:

```
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{<Required-Length-to-Fix-the-Problem>}
```

before the document begins - which indeed works. However, this fix requires to manually find the required length that fixes one's problem - which depends on the size of the longest Roman page number encountered in the document. On top of that, it shortens the dotted-line even for Arabic numbers when it is clearly not required.

**Preview of the Quick Fix Proposed by [@alephzero](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384991/roman-page-numbering-is-misaligned-in-toc-lof-and-lot-for-page-numbers-30)**

[image]

**Question**

How can one fix this problem so Roman page numbers are automatically right-aligned for all possible range of numbers and that the dotted-line is automatically generated to fill the empty gap between the title and the page number?

**Minimal Working Example (Without the Fix)**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{999}
\section{Page numbering using Arabic numbers}
\subsection{We can see that 999 is right-aligned as expected}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{999}
\section{Page numbering using Roman numbers}
\subsection{We can see that CMXCIX is not properly aligned}

\end{document}
```

**Minimal Working Example (With the Fix)**

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{5em} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{999}
\section{Page numbering using Arabic numbers}
\subsection{We can see that 999 is right-aligned as expected}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{999}
\section{Page numbering using Roman numbers}
\subsection{We can see that CMXCIX is not properly aligned}

\end{document}
```

**Accepted Solution of the Problem Proposed by @Werner (See Answer Below)**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft,etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\patchcmd{\cftsecfillnum}
{\makebox[\@pnumwidth][\cftpnumalign]}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\cftsubsecfillnum}
{\makebox[\@pnumwidth][\cftpnumalign]}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\cftsubsubsecfillnum}
{\makebox[\@pnumwidth][\cftpnumalign]}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\cftparafillnum}
{\makebox[\@pnumwidth][\cftpnumalign]}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\cftsubparafillnum}
{\makebox[\@pnumwidth][\cftpnumalign]}{}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{555}
\section{Page numbering using Arabic numbers}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{666}
\subsection{Sub-Section}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{777}
\subsubsection{Sub-Sub-Section}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{888}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{999}
\subparagraph{Sub-Paragraph}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{555}
\section{Page numbering using Roman numbers}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{666}
\subsection{Sub-Section}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{777}
\subsubsection{Sub-Sub-Section}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{888}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{999}
\subparagraph{Sub-Paragraph}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Well, this a reason why Roman numbers are so popular nowadays -- their pretty alignment ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - they ARE better than binary page numbers, to be sure.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer: I prefer Babylonian Page numbers, however ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer and MichaelPalmer: What about the Maya numeral system?! ;-) I understand and share your point of view. However, Roman numbers are still the norm in many cases such as for Appendices... which motivated me to ask this question to see if some people could come up with a "more automatic fix".

Comment: I'd suggest using Greek numbering – and ending proofs with Ε.Ε.Δ. instead of Q.E.D. ;o)

Comment: @OlivierGougeon: I see the point about the norm for page numbers in appendices in (some) cases, but is your document built of such many pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would only need to change those ToC entries with leaders. In your case, we can patch the `\subsection` ToC entry's way in which the page number is set by removing the box it is placed in. This also removes any alignment that might be visible, setting it as-is in line with the leader:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\cftsubsecfillnum}% <cmd>
  {\makebox[\@pnumwidth][\cftpnumalign]}% <search>
  {}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{999}
\section{Page numbering using Arabic numbers}
\subsection{We can see that 999 is right-aligned as expected}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{999}
\section{Page numbering using Roman numbers}
\subsection{We can see that CMXCIX is properly aligned}

\end{document}
```

We use [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) since it provides an identifiable structure for the ToC entries, and with something that is fairly easy (and understandable) to patch.

The patch (thanks to [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) takes the original structure that resembles

```
\newcommand{\cftsubsecfillnum}[1]{%
  {\cftsubsecleader}\nobreak
  \makebox[\@pnumwidth][\cftpnumalign]{\cftsubsecpagefont #1}\cftsubsecafterpnum\par
}
```

and changes it to

```
\newcommand{\cftsubsecfillnum}[1]{%
  {\cftsubsecleader}\nobreak
  {\cftsubsecpagefont #1}\cftsubsecafterpnum\par
}
```

so there's no boxing or alignment issue.

One can do the same for other entries in the ToC with leaders, if they exist (like `\subsubsection` or the like).

Comment: This is **exactly** the kind of _automatic fix_ that I was looking for! Thank you so much! For completeness sake, I would also add that the other patch commands are `\cftsecfillnum`, `\cftsubsecfillnum`, `\cftsubsubsecfillnum`, `\cftparafillnum` and `\cftsubparafillnum` for someone using respectively `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` with the `article` document class.